# How do I fit a gamma distribution to a pdf measured by maximum likelihood.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am terrible at statistics, nonetheless I was given the task of trying to figure out how to fit our company's data to a distribution using Maximum Likelihood Estimation. After a very long time banging my head on the wall, I'm asking for the internet's help.

I've tried everything I could understand from the results I got off Google, and wound up with a shape and rate pair that were completely useless(the gamma function was flat for the range of my data, and not fitted at all).

I'm hoping to explain how I understand what I'm supposed to do, and get my mistakes corrected.

- My data is supposed to be uniformly sampled (I tried binning to
  achieve this).
- Then by manipulating theta for the pdf ($\theta =
     (\alpha, \beta)$ for the case of Gamma) I find the values that maximize $\mathcal{L}(\vec{x};\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \Gamma(x_i;\theta)$
- I also tried measuring this as $\mathcal{L}(\vec{x};\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} ln(\Gamma(x_i;\theta))$ but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach sounds correct, but the devil may be in the details, which you are not providing. The only part that I have a question with is the "binning" procedure....if this affects the probability of a sample point being selected, then it will distort your analysis...better to just use all the raw sample points or sample with replacement.

Also, it may very well be a numerical issue...numerically finding MLEs is not simple plug and chug...different numerical methods have their strengths and weaknesses, so your numerical approach/method may not be able to handle your situration well. Try other packages or approaches if you can and see if that helps.

Also, I am assuming that a histogram of your data does not look flat...correct? Or that the empirical cumulative distribution function of your data does not resemble a straight line from 0 to 1. If they do, then your data are uniform...but that's probably not the case.

Since your company seems intent to torment you with statistical problems, you should become familar with the [NIST Statistical manual](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/index.htm). I've found it quite handy and it doesn't blather on. For your specific problem, I refer to you this [chapter](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366b.htm). See the correct formulae towards the bottom.

Comment: I am fairly confident in my binning at least, as a histogram of the results is very similar to the source data, neither of which are flat (or even very linear). One thing I'm worried about is that I'm having a hard time finding a definition of the joint pdf function that I can understand, and as such may be defining that incorrectly.

Comment: @Camden Narzt The mle for the gamma is a pretty well established problem. Take a look at the link I sent you on the gamma distribution, it has the formulae you need to fit a gamma via mle